# which is the C# declaration equivalent of delphi "class of " (type of class)?

Tags: c#, delphi

In delphi I can declare a *type of class* like so

```
type
  TFooClass = class of TFoo;
  TFoo=class
  end;
```

Which is the C# equivalent for this declaration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The closest you can get in C# is the `Type` type, which contains the metadata about a type.

```
public class A { }
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
  Type b = typeof(A);
}
```

It's not *exactly* the same. In Delphi, "type of othertype" is itself a type that you can assign to a variable. In C# "type of othertype" is a `System.Type` instance that can be assigned to any variables of type `System.Type`.

As an example, in Delphi, you can do this:

```
type
  TAClass = class of TA;
  TA = class
  public
    class procedure DoSomething;
  end;

var x : TAClass;
begin
  x := TA;
  x.DoSomething();
end;
```

You cannot do anything like this in C#; you cannot call static methods of type A from instances of `Type` that happen to hold `typeof(A)`, nor can you define a variable that can *only* hold `typeof(A)` or derived types.

(Some specific patterns that Delphi metaclass types are used for, can be accomplished using generics:

```
public class A { }
public class ListOfA<T> where T: A { }
```

In this case, T is the "type of A" or whatever derived class of A was used to construct the class.)

Comment: One of the really nice language features that Delphi has that C# doesn't.

Comment: Is this still missing from C#?

Comment: Yes, the ability to create a reference to a specific class type isn't part of C#, and I don't see it being added any time soon. You can generally use reflection and/or generics to achieve all the same goals, so I don't see it as particularly high priority.